# Redirected to OpenDNS despite having no OpenDNS IP in the DNS settings

Tags: opendns

I can't seem to get rid of OpenDNS on my Windows 10 machine. I tried everything. I'm at home, connected to my private wi-fi router, and don't use any VPN or proxy. I've manually configured the network connection to use the Google DNS, both for IPv4 and IPv6. I've also put the Google DNS in the group policy (in Administrative Templates/Network/DNS Client), which is supposed to take precedence over anything else. I've flushed the DNS cache. I've even put the Google DNS in my router's config.
To no avail.
Every time I try to navigate to a certain web page on this computer, my request is immediately redirected to blocked.opendns.com, and then immediately to blocked.*[my company]*.com, which tells me that the web site violates my company's policy.
The same happens if I use the IP address of the blocked site instead of its name. Using https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in the Chrome address bar will take me to OpenDNS and then to the blocked message.

How can I get rid of this redirection? I have administrator rights on this machine.

From time to time it does work. Last week, after I put the Google DNS in the group policy, I was able to visit that web site. I thought I had solved it, but today it's again not working. So it must be something else. But I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Any ideas?
Thank you.